# TinyMCE deleting text doesnt update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have added the Classic TinyMCE editor to my website (angularjs version) and have the problem that when typing something into the editor, deleting it, and typing in something else doesn't update correctly.

When I write in "Test Support answer", delete it and then type "Maybe it'll work?"
and submit the ticket response, the outcome will be "Test Supp".

This only happens when the whole message is deleted. Deleting part of the message don't seem to cause any problems.

Did anyone else have any similar problem and may know a way of fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. Implemented it different on another site and there it seems to work fine. Im not sure what's causing the problem but here's how I fixed it.

Old Implementation:

```
<form method="post"  ng-controller="TinyMceController">

<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="ticketContent"></textarea> </br>
<button type="button" ng-controller="ticket-answer" ng-click="addAnswerAction()" style="background:#ff6464;color:#fff !important;">Create</button>

</form>
```

New Implementation (that fixed it):

```
<form method="post" >
<div ng-controller="TinyMceController">
<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="ticketContent"></textarea> </br>
<button type="button" ng-click="addAnswerAction(textContent)">Create</button>
</div>
</form>
```